# How do I say "What martial art did Bruce Lee use?" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "What martial art did Bruce Lee use" in German?

> Welche Kampfkunst hat Bruce Lee gemacht?

Bruce Lee ist der Begründer der Kampfkunst Jeet Kune Do.

Comment: why the downvotes?? this is a valid question. it gives an original sentence, and a translation attempt... it may not be pretty, but hey, you can edit for that.

Comment: Apart: "Begründer" wird nicht wirklich verwendet (=sehr selten). Am besten ist hier die Formulierung von Wikipedia: "Jeet Kune Do wurde von Bruce Lee entwickelt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Welchen Kampfkunststil wendete Bruce Lee an?

This translation focuses on the style *used* by Bruce Lee in an unnamed context.

Your second phrase indicates a slightly different meaning. A suitable question to this provided answer could be:

> Welcher Kampfkunststil wurde durch Bruce Lee begründet?

or

> Welchen Kampfkunststil begründete Bruce Lee?

or

> Welcher Kampfkunststil wurde durch Bruce Lee geprägt?

or

> Welchen Kampfkunststil prägte Bruce Lee?